# Headers and Cable for a LCD and UI?

Tags: pcb-design, connector, cables, ribbon-cable

My current layout consists of two 16 pin (8x2) 2.54mm pitch (shrouded) headers. One is for an 16x2 LCD screen and the other will be for a button interface as well as status LEDs which will be mounted on the front panel. Size is an issue and the headers are taking up way too much space on the PCB. I'm not even using all 16 pins on either of the headers - I chose to go with 16 to make it easier cable setup for the 16 pin LCD (Scientific, I know), I'm actually only using 12 for the LCD and 10 for the UI. I also liked the fact that its the same parts for both headers.

What would be my best option for something size and cost efficient? Would it be better to look for a smaller pitch or a different style of connection all together? Is flex cable a viable option? I've never used it and what I've seen of it, it looks custom with its odd shapes and connectors. Or should I just drop my current headers down to the actual pin sizes I actually need?

Comment: What sort of component technology are you using? Is it only through-hole, or does it include SMD? Is it okay to introduce SMD if the board isn't using it already? Are you using a commercial PCB manufacturer, or is it DIY, or veroboard? What is the smallest pin spacing you are comfortable with, is 1mm pitch okay? Is the design in a case where it is tight for space, or is their plenty of room for slightly over long cables? Do the connectors need to endure more than, say, 100 plug/unplug operations?

Comment: FFCs come almost exclusively in two standard pitches - 1mm and 0.5mm (and perhaps 1.27mm). The disadvantage is that it must be purchased in correct width and length. Connectors are mostly surface-mounted, although through-hole also exist. Compared with ribbon cables, they are not nearly as rugged and flexible but save a lot of space (and also look more professional).

Comment: @gbulmer yes, all of my components are smd. it will be in a case but vertical space shouldn't be a problem. and they will never be unplugged. and the PCBs will be done by a manufacturer.

Comment: Switching to a serial or multiplexed interface would save you connections and thus space (and probably simplify board layout too) - at the cost of something smarter on the far end of course.

Answer (score 1):

To save space on the PCB, you could use Flexible flat cable (FFC) (also referred to as Flexible Printed Circuits, or FPC)

AFAIK, they have a limited plug/unplug life, but are okay for a few operations.

As well as traditional electronics distrubutors, Internet resellers (ebay, [Aliexpress](http://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?SearchText=FFC), etc.) sell a large range of FFC parts, in modest quantity at lower cost.

Of course, you still have the problem of choosing the number of conductors.

The lower-prices are typically for many-off quantities. Also you might want to reduce your BoM variety. So might prefer to choose a single part for both connections. You may also prefer to retain some flexibility in future, so you might increase the number of pins above your current minimum.

The smaller pitch cables have lower current carrying capacity (though adequate for many applications), so you might want to allow for a several pins for power and ground.

Some of the sellers listed on Chinese sales sites will make custom sizes.